# Visual Studio open cmd.exe with Consolas

Tags: c, character-encoding, console, visual-studio-2012, cmd

I have a program written in C and it's beeing developed under Visual Studio 2012.
My program uses characters not available in Raster fonts, so I changed `cmd.exe` font to Consolas and my characters (á, é, í, etc.) worked.

But, when I open my program, the console still remains in Raster font. I don't know where I should change to make the Consolas globally accepted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use SetCurrentConsoleFontEx().  Won't work on XP.

Answer (score 1):

Here some code I scraped together from several sources.
Allows me to use codepages, avoids unicode.
However, wprintf() etc should work, too.

Only consolas and lucida console work sofar. Includes an attempt to get a similar size.

Checks include the validitycheck of the nFont index.
That may be unneeded, in which case you can leave out the undocumented call to kernel32 routine GetNumberOfConsoleFonts().

Hans says it won't work on XP, [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686200%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) say minimum _WIN32_WINNT is 0x500 which would include XP. Haven't tried yet.
Jan

```
static void strcpytoW(WCHAR *dst, const char *src)
{
    WCHAR c;
    while ((c=*src++)!=0) *dst++=c;
    *dst=0;
}

/*************************************/

typedef DWORD (WINAPI *FN_NUMCONSOLEFONT)();
FN_NUMCONSOLEFONT GetNumberOfConsoleFonts;
static bool setfont(const HANDLE h, char *facename, CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX &in,CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX &out)
{
    in.cbSize=out.cbSize=sizeof(in);
    strcpytoW(in.FaceName,facename);
    if (!SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(h,FALSE,&in)) return false;
    HMODULE hm = ::GetModuleHandleA("KERNEL32.DLL"); 
    if (!hm) return false;
    GetNumberOfConsoleFonts = (FN_NUMCONSOLEFONT) GetProcAddress(hm, "GetNumberOfConsoleFonts");
    if (!GetNumberOfConsoleFonts) return false;
    DWORD numConsoleFonts=GetNumberOfConsoleFonts();
    if (!GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(h,FALSE,&out)) return false;
    return out.nFont>=0 && out.nFont<numConsoleFonts && _wcsicmp(in.FaceName,out.FaceName)==0;
}

/*************************************/

static char *set_console(char *facename,int page)
{
    HANDLE hStdout = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX fi={sizeof(fi),-1,{0,0},54,700},newfi;
    CONSOLE_FONT_INFO curfi;
    if (!GetCurrentConsoleFont(hStdout,FALSE,&curfi)) return NULL;
    for (fi.dwFontSize=curfi.dwFontSize;;fi.dwFontSize.Y++)
    {
        if (!setfont(hStdout,facename,fi,newfi))
        {
            facename="Lucida Console";
            if (!setfont(hStdout,facename,fi,newfi)) return NULL;
        }
        if (newfi.dwFontSize.X>=curfi.dwFontSize.X) break;
    }
    if (!SetConsoleOutputCP(page)) return NULL;
    return facename;
}

/*************************************/

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *faceused;
    if ((faceused=set_console("Consolas",1252))!=NULL)
        printf("Console succesful, using %s\n",faceused);
    else puts("Console failed");
    puts("\x86 \x87 \xa7 \xa9 \xae \xb1 \xbc");
```

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl-F5 to start executing the program.  Before it returns to VS, it says "Press any key...".  This gives you the opportunity to click on the window's upper left corner, properties and change the font to raster fonts there, too.

Comment: I know, I did that. Although, as I'm deploying my program to other people, I want it to do this automatically or by .reg modifications.

Comment: Oops. Use Procmon to find out what happens when you do that?